# How can I use jQuery to remove a class from DataTables paginated pages?

Tags: jquery, css, pagination, datatables, removeclass

That question is wordy, but let me explain:

I have a column in my DataTable table that I can edit (using jEditable).

I give that column the class `jeditable` (through the DataTables option) which picks up some CSS formatting (blue background).

Then I make the column editable with the jEditable function.

At a specific point, I'd like to make that column uneditable, and remove the blue background.

I call `$(.jeditable).editable('disable')` which perfectly disables the editing on all columns of my table.

I also call `$('.jeditable').removeClass("jeditable");` to remove the blue background CSS formatting. This removes the blue background from that column, as expected.

However, when I go to any of the paginated pages, while they are not editable, they're still blue, because they still have the `jeditable` class.

Is there any method to remove a class from ALL elements in HTML, regardless of if they're visible?

Comment: `.removeClass` should still work on non-visible elements.  It's possible that they're built by DataTable dynamically

Comment: This was what I was worried about. I suppose I'll need to search for a solution that involves the table being re-created...

Comment: remove the class etc at a different point - not sure how you paging works but when you click the paging buttton or somewhere around this event remove the classes again.

Comment: That is how I have implemented it, and it works fine. Thanks.